# Prolog taking inverse of a predicate

Tags: prolog

I got a database that looks like

```
hasChild(person1, person2).
hasChild(person1, person3).
hasChild(person4, person5).
```

Which means that (for example) person1 has child named person2.

I then create a predicate that identifies if the person is a parent

```
parent(A):- hasChild(A,_).
```

Which identifies if the person is a parent, i.e. has any children

Then I try to create a predicate `childless(A)` that should return true if the user doesn't have any children which is basically an inverse of `parent(A)`.

So I have 2 questions here:

a) is it possible to somehow take an "inverse" of a predicate, like `childless(A):-not(parent(A)).` or in any other way bypass this using the `hasChild` or any other method?

b) `parent(A)` will return true multiple times if the person has multiple children. Is it possible to make it return true only once?

Comment: IMO you use the word "inverse" rather loosely. Get more, better answers by rephrasing your question!

Comment: @repeat the question is tagged "prolog," not "semantics." :)

Comment: @DanielLyons. Right! Either way the message is clear: Ask better questions (and you'll get more and better answers). Quite often "getting the question out of one's own head" (right, so *other* people can grasp it, too) is more than half the way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For problem 1, yes. Prolog is not entirely magically delicious to some because it conflates negation and failure, but you can definitely write:

```
childless(X) :- \+ hasChild(X, _).
```

and you will see "true" for people that do not have children. You will also see "true" for vegetables, minerals, ideologies, procedures, shoeboxes, beer recipes and unfeathered bipeds. If this is a problem for you, a simple solution is to improve your data model, but complaining about Prolog is a very popular alternative. :)

For problem 2, the simplest solution is to use `once`:

```
parent(A) :- once(hasChild(A, _)).
```

This is a safer alternative to using the cut operator, which would look like this:

```
parent(A) :- hasChild(A, _), !.
```

This has a fairly significant cost: `parent/1` will only generate a single valid solution, though it will verify other correct solutions. To wit:

```
?- parent(X).
X = person1.
```

Notice it did not suggest `person4`. However,

```
?- childless(person4).
true.
```

This asymmetry is certainly a "code smell" to most any intermediate Prolog programmer such as myself. It's as though Prolog has some sort of amnesia or selective hearing depending on the query. This is no way to get invited to high society events!

I would suggest that the best solution here (which handles the mineral/vegetable problem above as well) is to add some more facts about people. After all, a person exists before they have kids (or do they?) so they are not "defined" by that relationship. But continuing to play the game, you may be able to circumvent the problem using `setof/3` to construct a list of all the people:

```
parent(Person) :- 
  setof(X, C^hasChild(X, C), People), 
  member(Person, People).
```

The odd expression `C^hasChild(X, C)` tells Prolog that C is a free variable; this ensures that we get the set of all things in the first argument of `hasChild/2` bound to the list `People`. This is not first-order logic anymore folks! And the advantage here is that `member/2` will generate for us as well as check:

```
?- parent(person4).
true.

?- parent(X).
X = person1 ;
X = person4.
```

Is this efficient? No. Is it smart? Probably not. Is it a solution to your question that also generates? Yes, it seems to be. Well, one out of three ain't bad. :)

As a final remark, some Prolog implementations treat `not/1` as an alias for `\+/1`; if you happen to be using one of them, I recommend you not mistake compatibility with pre-ISO conventions for a jovial tolerance for variety: correct the spelling of `not(X)` to `\+ X`. :)

Comment: s(X) for suggesting to improve the data model.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you could do it!

> Define *everything* you know for a fact as a Prolog fact, no matter if it is positive or negative.

In your sample, we define "positives" like `person/1` *and* "negatives" like `childless/1`. Of course, we also define the predicates `child_of/2`, `male/1`, `female/1`, `spouse_husband/2`, and so on.

Note that we have introduced quite a bit of redundancy into the database.

In return, we got a clearer line of [knowns/unknowns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns) without resorting to higher-order constructs.

We need to define the right data consistency constraints:

```
% There is no person which is neither male nor female.
:- \+ (person(X), \+ (male(X) ; female(X))).

% Nobody is male and female (at once).
:- \+ (male(X), female(X)).

% Nobody is childless and parental (at once).
:- \+ (childless(X), child_of(_,X)).

% There is no person which is neither childless nor parental.
:- \+ (person(X), \+ (childless(X) ; child_of(_,X))).

% There is no child which is not a person.
:- \+ (child_of(X,_), \+ person(X)).

% There is no parent which is not a person.
:- \+ (child_of(_,X), \+ person(X)).

% (...plus, quite likely, a lot more integrity constraints...)
```

This is just a rough sketch... Depending on your use-cases you could do the modeling differently, e.g. using relations like `parental/1` together with suitable  integrity constraints. YMMY! HTH